# Angular2 app making rogue request for https://myurl/null on loading of pages

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 RC5 app that is hosted at the dev link https://tilecasev2.azurewebsites.net

I am using hash strategy routing.

The app does talk to a Web API back end.

My problem is that when the app loads I am seeing some requests being make to https://tilecasev2.azurewebsites.net/null

These are resulting in a 404 and a message saying...

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I have been through my code and it doesn't look like I am making these requests myself. Does anyone know why Angular might be making them?

I have attached a screenshot of the requests in Chrome...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue, and after looking into my code. I found that code
`<img [src]="imgSrc" />`
causes this problem. In my code `imgSrc:string = null;` is the initial value, it will send a `/null` request. So setting `imgSrc: string = "data:image/png;base64,ffff";` could solve this issue.

Deal in the same way with other elements with `src` attribute which set in similar way.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I will try this solution shortly and will let you know the result.

Comment: I just tried this and it has fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When browser finds `<img src="">` tag it sends HTTP GET request to Server for URL inside `src` tag. If you are setting URL dynamically then you have to check whatever URL value is initialized or not else browser consider `null` value as URL and try to make HTTP GET request.

```
<div class="img" *ngIf="imageURL">
     <img [src]="imageURL">
</div>
```